# Assigning signatures in Erdas Imagine 2016

Tags: erdas-imagine

I am having a problem in creating new signatures in Signature Editor in ERDAS 2016. Whenever I click on the icon to add signatures a pallette pops up that says:

```
"ERROR GETTING AOI FROM VIEWER, USE AOI TOOLS IN VIEWER TO CREATE AOIs FOR SIGNATURE EDITOR"
```

I can't proceed from here and I am new to Erdas so I can't comprehend too.

Answer (score 1):

For the creation of signature files in ERDAS IMAGINE you have to create your training data. You need to pick features (polygons) from your image. For doing that you have to select the **AOI (area of interest)** tool.
open the image to the subset in the viewer, and draw a closed loop AOI (AOI 
Tools) using the create rectangle or polygon AOI tool. Save the 
AOI as an AOI layer which plays a crucial role in the creation of signature files.